# Subclassing a class with closures over private methods

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy class that happens to have closures calling private methods. It works just fine until I try to create a subclass of it, resulting in `MissingMethodException`.

Sample code:

```
class SomeClass {
    void doStuff() {
        println(['a', 'b'].collect { toUpper(it) })
    }

    private String toUpper(String x) {
        return x.toUpperCase()
    }
}

class Wat {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def x = new SomeClass() {}
        x.doStuff()
    }
}
```

... crashes with:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.example.Wat.toUpper() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [a]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1573)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1559)
    ...
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a sane way out, other than making all methods protected?

Comment: For the records: `@CompileStatic` makes that also work.

Comment: This issue is being tracked as GROOVY-5438. The solution for static compilation is the generation of synthetic bridge methods, which is a for of the "pass" intermediary example below. https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/GROOVY-5438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
class SomeClass {
    void doStuff() {
        println(['a', 'b'].collect { toUpper(it) })
    }

    String toUpper(String x) {
        return x.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

You could also mark `toUpper` with `protected` or `public` and it would also work.  `private` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot come with a better solution but to use an intermediate function:

```
class SomeClass {
    void doStuff() {
        println(['a', 'b'].collect { pass(it) })
    }

    def pass(x) { toUpper(x) }

    private String toUpper(String x) {
        x.toUpperCase()
    }
}


def x = new SomeClass() {}
x.doStuff()
```

Comment: That extra method (`pass`) works because it isn't private.  You could just as well make `toUpper` non-private and eliminate the interim stack frame.